# Increasing gain of PMOS two-stage op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pmos

I am trying to increase the gain of a two-stage PMOS op-amp I have designed below shown in this schematics:

[image: LTSpice model for 2-stage PMOS op-amp]

The gain currently hovers slightly below 71dB, but I have to increase it to above 75dB. I am lost at which parameters to tune as some of the parameters seem interlinked to one another, though I am aware overall that Av = gm*rout.

[image: Gain of two-stage PMOS op-amp]

I need to keep the Vswing at above 1.0Vpp, while I have designed on paper, to have Vout = 1.5V.

May I ask for advice on this?

Thank you so much! :)

**Update 1**: I have managed to get the desired gain after increasing channel width and tuning M6. However, I realized my output swing is not symmetrical and I suspect there is clipping at the bottom. May I ask how should I resolve this? I have tried changing the aspect ratios of M3, M4 and M6 but to no avail.

[image: Attempt 1: Schematic achieving >75dB DC gain]

[image: Output swing of setup above]

**Update 2**: I have further tuned the specs to make the output swing up and down approximately equal, with the new schematics and plot below:

[image: Attempt 2: Schematics output swing @75.7dB]

[image: Output swing of the above setup]

Answer (score 1):

Make the two bottom NCH to have stiffer Rout----use longer channel devices.

Comment: Thank you analogsystemsrf for your advice. May I ask do you mean make M3 and M4 have larger length, while keeping that aspect ratios to be the same?

Comment: For precision matching (e.g. low input offset), large area FETS are the standard approach, along with large (Vgs - Vt). Here you are just learning, by simulation.Try several approaches: same W/L with larger L; same W and longer L. Observe how the output offset voltage changes. Have fun.